# Combining Java 8 Lambda with annotations

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Considering the following code:

```
public class MyTest {
public void sayHello(Supplier<String> myGetter) {
    System.out.println("Hello " + myGetter.get());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person person = new Person("Michal", "Lefler");
    MyTest myTest = new MyTest();

    List<Supplier<String>> suppliers = new ArrayList<>();
    suppliers.add(person::getName);
    suppliers.add(person::getLastName);

    suppliers.forEach(myTest::sayHello);
}

static class Person {
    private String name;
    private String lastName;

    public Person(String name, String lastName) {
       this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @NameMethod
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @NameMethod
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getBlahBlah() {
        return "BlahBlah";
    }

    public String getPakaPaka() {
        return "PakaPaka";
    }
}

@interface NameMethod {}
}
```

My question is:
Instead of filling the suppliers list explicitly:

```
    suppliers.add(person::getName);
    suppliers.add(person::getLastName);
```

I would like to fill the suppliers list automatically, using the "@NameMethod" annotation. I mean that I would like to scan all the "@NameMethod" annotated methods, using reflection, and then to somehow add these methods to the suppliers list.
Is there a way I can do it?
How?
Thanks.

Comment: You've already thought about it and found an acceptable solution, so what exactly is the problem? What blocks you from writing the code?

Comment: I did *not* find any solution. What make you think that I did? I have no idea how to combine the @NameMethod annotation with the lambda expressions.

Comment: Yes you did: "I would like to scan all the "@NameMethod" annotated methods, using reflection, and then to somehow add these methods to the suppliers list". That's a solution. Again, what is blocking you from coding that? That's what your question should be about: what blocks you from going further.

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection as you suggest and check for the annotation and create a supplier for each method.

```
Person p = ...
for (Method m : Person.class.getMethods()) 
    if (m.getAnnotation(NameMethod.class) != null)
        suppliers.add(() -> {
            try {
                 return m.invoke(p);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                 throw new AssertionError(e);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I am a little concerned about the performance of m.invoke() ? Does anyone know how it would perform?

Comment: @MartinMeeser In this case, it is about as expensive as creating the lambda each time and much cheaper than calling `getMethods()`. It costs a fraction of a micro-second.

Comment: So is the m.invoke equally fast then a normal call? Can you help me with that?

Comment: @MartinMeeser A normal call is about 0.05 microseconds, or it can be inlined for no cost at all. It's more expensive, but its not the worst part of this code.

Answer (score 1):

A Supplier is just an interface that you can implement.

```
public static class NameSupplier implements Supplier<String> {

    private final Method method;
    private final Object object;

    public NameSupplier(Method method, Object object) {
        this.method = method;
        this.object = object;
    }

    @Override
    public String get() {
        try {
            return (String) method.invoke(object);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

If you use reflection, you can get all methods that are annotated with @NameMethod

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person person = new Person("Michal", "Lefler");
    MyTest myTest = new MyTest();

    List<Supplier<String>> suppliers = new ArrayList<>();
    Method[] methods = Person.class.getMethods();
    for (Method method : methods) {
        if (!method.isAnnotationPresent(NameMethod.class))
            continue;
        suppliers.add(new NameSupplier(method, person));
    }

    suppliers.forEach(myTest::sayHello);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! 
Both answers were very helpful.
I would like to suggest my solution, based on yours, but avoid using reflection for the routine method invocation (we have performance restrictions). Instead, I'm using  "MethodHandle" objects.

```
public class MyTest {
public void sayHello(Supplier<String> myGetter) {
    System.out.println("Hello " + myGetter.get());
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException {
    Person person = new Person("Michal", "Lefler");
    MyTest myTest = new MyTest();

    List<Supplier<String>> suppliers = new ArrayList<>();
    Method[] methods = Person.class.getMethods();
    for (Method method : methods) {
        if (!method.isAnnotationPresent(NameMethod.class))
            continue;
        MethodType desc = MethodType.methodType(String.class);
        MethodHandle methodHandle = MethodHandles.lookup().findVirtual(
                Person.class, method.getName(), desc);
        suppliers.add(new NameSupplier<>(methodHandle, person));
    }

    suppliers.forEach(myTest::sayHello);
}

static class Person {
    private String name;
    private String lastName;

    public Person(String name, String lastName) {
       this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @NameMethod
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @NameMethod
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getBlahBlah() {
        return "BlahBlah";
    }

    public String getPakaPaka() {
        return "PakaPaka";
    }
}

@Retention(value= RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface NameMethod {}

public static class NameSupplier<T> implements Supplier<String> {

    private final MethodHandle methodHandle;
    private final T object;

    public NameSupplier(MethodHandle methodHandle, T object) {
        this.methodHandle = methodHandle;
        this.object = object;
    }

    @Override
    public String get() {
        try {
            return (String) methodHandle.invoke(object);
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throw new RuntimeException(throwable);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You could run the reflective code on initialization of the class and cache the result. That way it will only run it once. The class will not change during runtime.